# AngularJS not able to type in textbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, textbox

At the moment I try to implement an app with AngularJS. At first my problem: I am not able to type text into a textbox.

I have a `zoomService` which increments and decrements the zoom property. The user is able to zoom with a slider, buttons and a textbox but unfortunatelly the part with the textbox doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```js
"use strict";

app.service("zoomService", ["$rootScope", function ($rootScope) {

    var data = {
        zoom: 100,
        upperBound: 200, // TODO: Aus Konfigurationsdatei lesen
        lowerBound: 20 // TODO: Aus Konfigurationsdatei lesen
    };

    return {
        data: data,

        increment: function() {
            if ($rootScope.$root.$$phase != "$apply" && $rootScope.$root.$$phase != "$digest") {
                $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                    if (data.zoom + 1 <= data.upperBound)
                        data.zoom++;
                });
            } else {
                if (data.zoom + 1 <= data.upperBound)
                    data.zoom++;
            }
        },

        decrement: function() {
            if ($rootScope.$root.$$phase != "$apply" && $rootScope.$root.$$phase != "$digest") {
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    if (data.zoom - 1 >= data.lowerBound)
                        data.zoom--;
                });
            } else {
                if (data.zoom - 1 >= lowerBound)
                    data.zoom--;
            }
        },

        reset: function() {
            if ($rootScope.$root.$$phase != "$apply" && $rootScope.$root.$$phase != "$digest") {
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    data.zoom = 100;
                });
            } else {
                data.zoom = 100;
            }
        }
    }
}]);

app.controller("StartController", ["$scope", "zoomService", function($scope, zoomService) {

    $scope.zoom = zoomService;

}]);
```

```html
<div data-ng-show="project.data.project !== null" class="zoom top-right">
    <div>
        <form name="zoomForm" data-ng-init="setFormScope(this)">
            <img src="/styles/images/16x16/FI_Verkleinern.png" data-ng-click="zoom.decrement()" alt="Zoom -" title="Zoom -" />
            <input class="slider" type="range" min="{{zoom.data.lowerBound}}" max="{{zoom.data.upperBound}}" data-ng-model="zoom.data.zoom" />
            <img src="/styles/images/16x16/FI_Vergroessern.png" data-ng-click="zoom.increment()" alt="Zoom +" title="Zoom +"/>
            <input name="directZoom" type="text" data-ng-minlength="2" data-ng-maxlength="3" data-ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{2,3}$/" data-ng-model="zoom.data.zoom" data-ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}" data-ng-keyup="cancel($event)" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am happy about every small hint which I could solve this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you prepare jsfiddle for this?

Comment: you have a error - used `lowerBound` in `decrement` instead `data.lowerBound` and also seems like in your case better `factory` instead `service`

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/nkBH5Q0c31UIwNGJivPA?p=preview

Now I have created a plunkr and there it works but on my system it doesn't. I am really confused! My hole app is much bigger then this snippet maybe there are some other side effects? How could I detect such ugly side effects?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There could be a parent element (`md-select` in my case) that is eating your key down events. To fix this, try adding `onkeydown="event.stopPropagation()"` to the input tag. This will prevent the event from reaching the parent element, so it can't call `preventDefault()` anymore.

Example:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="zoom.data.zoom" ... onkeydown="event.stopPropagation()" />
```

If that doesn't work, try looking for any other code that might be calling `preventDefault()` and eating your keydown events.

It's also possible that you have some logic that is reverting the model value back to its original value as soon as you type. Check for any `ng-change` or `$watch` events that might be doing this. Although this is probably not the issue if you use `{updateOn: 'blur'}`.

Comment: Calling `preventDefault()` from a parent element was the main culprit in my case. Your suggestion is right to the point: using `stopPropagation()` in the keyDown event handler did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

When you have

```
ng-model-options={updateOn: 'blur'}
```

set, the value will be updated only after user leaver the input field. If you remove this code, the update is instantaneous. Here's the reproduced example http://jsbin.com/nogegutize/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Consider pasting the code in answer instead of providing link(s); which could go dead.

Comment: It is ok but I need this ng-model-option!

Comment: @PatrickVogt but this option says "update the value when user leaves the input" and it is precisely what happens. You want to update the value on keyup instead of telling it to only update it on blur? ;)

Comment: @TomekSułkowski I want to update the value on blur but the problem is that I just cannot type anything in any textbox on my app! It's so depressingly :(